# Stack two vertical LinearLayout in LinearLayout horizontally

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin.android

I'm trying to stack two vertical LinearLayout in LinearLayout horizontally.
My code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:text="User Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/txtusername" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Date registration"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/txtdateregistr" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Phone number"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/txtphonenumb" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horisontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
            <TextView
                android:text="Count"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/ordercountnumb" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Ordr"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/ordercount" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
            <TextView
                android:text="Count"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/deliverycountnumb" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Delv"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/deliverycount" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Also everything looks as I and has conceived:

[image: Also everything looks as I and has conceived]

And the scheme for full understanding:

[image]

But when I compile that in VS2015 see error "String types not allowed (at 'orientation' with value 'horisontal')". Need help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a typo.

Change,

```
android:orientation="horisontal"
```

to

```
android:orientation="horizontal"
```

Comment: horisontal nice :)

Answer (score 0):

In the root  use below attribute

wheightSum="10"

and in child  view use wheight = "5" for each child  view

Note: on base layout use   android:orientation="horizontal" for horizontal display or  android:orientation="vertical" for vertical display

Answer (score 0):

Error in LinearLayout orientation.It should be horizontal or remove this.(**By default Linear layout has horizontal orientation.** )

```
     <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:text="User Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/txtusername" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Date registration"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/txtdateregistr" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Phone number"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/txtphonenumb" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px">
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
            <TextView
                android:text="Count"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/ordercountnumb" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Ordr"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/ordercount" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:minWidth="25px"
            android:minHeight="25px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
            <TextView
                android:text="Count"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/deliverycountnumb" />
            <TextView
                android:text="Delv"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/deliverycount" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```